# Multi-Dimentional Array, how to display else statement once?

Tags: c++

I have this Matrix of 3 by 3 `Matrix[3][3]`. My task was to Display Row number of the matrix containing at least two Prime Numbers, I have done this Prime number work but the problem is, I have to display this message once `cout << "No row containing at least two prime numbers" << endl;`. Due to iteration, if any row does not contain two prime numbers or only one row containing two prime numbers, it displays me this three times/two times. i want the message to display only once if there is none or any.

PRIME NUMBER CODE...

```
cout << "ROW NUMBER CONTAINING AT LEAST TWO PRIME NUMBERS" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            Prime = 0;
            for (int k = 2; k < Matrix[i][j]; k++)
            {
                if (Matrix[i][j] % k == 0)
                {
                    Prime = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (Prime == 0)
            {
                Count += 1;
            }
        }
        if (Count == 2)
        {
            cout << "ROW NUMBER " << i + 1 << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "NO ROW CONTAINING AT LEAST TWO PRIME NUMBERS" << endl;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a integer like a flag.

```cpp
    int flag = 0;
    cout << "ROW NUMBER CONTAINING AT LEAST TWO PRIME NUMBERS" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            Prime = 0;
            for (int k = 2; k < Matrix[i][j]; k++)
            {
                if (Matrix[i][j] % k == 0)
                {
                    Prime = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (Prime == 0)
            {
                Count += 1;
            }
        }
        if (Count == 2)
        {
            cout << "ROW NUMBER " << i + 1 << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            flag++;
        }
    }
    if(flag == 3)
    {
        cout << "NO ROW CONTAINING AT LEAST TWO PRIME NUMBERS" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: This does not solve OP's problem. The "NO ROW" message will be shown if there is any row that does not contain two prime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another count variable

```
int row_count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{

    ...

    if (Count == 2)
    {
        cout << "ROW NUMBER " << i + 1 << endl;
        row_count += 1;
    }
}
if (row_count == 0)
    cout << "NO ROW CONTAINING AT LEAST TWO PRIME NUMBERS" << endl;
```

Not the most beautiful code in the word, but it does the job.

BTW *at least two prime numbers*, so

```
if (Count == 2)
```

should be

```
if (Count >= 2)
```